# Multiple modules in a page ZF2

Tags: module, frameworks, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend framework 2 and I want to load several modules in one URL... but i don't know how to do that, I tried to play with route but nothing worked...

So here I am!

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that you need to choose (perhaps create) ONE module and define the appropriate url route in there, then reference your other modules using the service manager and view helpers from your controller function and view respectively. So it all orients around a single controller function which makes calls to the other modules.

If you still need help with this let me know and I'll try to find you some code examples by the end of the weekend. Also, let me know exactly what you're trying to do (partly so I can help but partly out of curiosity).